# mod-rewrite is skipping first matching rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a mod rewrite in my .htaccess file with a couple rewrite entries:

```
RewriteRule ^/services/(\w+)$ controllers/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]
```

Whenever I go to http://blah.com/services/something it redirects me to the index of blah.com rather than matching the first rule and then stopping.

also: if I change the last rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.html [L]
```

the application "works," just not when there are additional paths after the first /.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If that's in an .htaccess, you should _not_ use a leading `/`.  Just match `^services/...`

Comment: Since it's parsed in a directory context, the rewrite engine does not receive the leading `/` as part of the URI.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I took out the leading / and it's still redirecting to the index

Comment: If you comment out the index rule, does it match `services/`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If you really have a `[L]` and it matches when the index rule isn't present, it should also match when the index rule is replaced.  You'll probably need to enable [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) to debug it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you're telling me...I'll look up how to set that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule (`RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]`) is too generic and will rewrite everything to your index page when invoked from an htaccess file. After the redirect from services/something to services/controller/something.php , the root htaccess is invoked once again, the first rule does not apply (there is no match), so it goes to the second which does match.

I can think of 3 things that could help:

1) Have you tried using the END flag?

```
RewriteRule ^/services/(\w+)$ controllers/$1.php [END]
```

2) In your `services/controller` directory place an htaccess that will invalidate your root level htaccess. E.g. with a directive `RewriteEngine off`

3) Make your redirect to index rule more specific by using a list of RewriteCond directives.

Comment: both 1 and 2 worked for me.  I'm trying to get angular html5 routing to work and anything more specific doesn't seem to work.